# using a javascript variable with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that can be toggled with a switch and I am using this script across pages. When I toggle the switch on one page and go to the next I can see that the variable has changed to its default. I have tried to use localStorage to store the variable but this didn't work

script without local storage:

```
function toggleDarkMode() {  
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

script with local storage:

```
function darkMode(){
    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode"));
}
```

Am I saving the variable correctly and if so how do I access it?

Comment: It will be `window.localStorage` in your code

Comment: I have tried this and still going to another page would reset the value

Comment: Maybe your `darkMode` function is resetting the value every time a new page is loaded and this is causing the problem. Add a check to see if the value exists before toggling the value.

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly setting the value by

```
function darkMode(){
    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode"));
}
```

To read the value you have to do this

```
let valueFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('dark-mode');
```

Check a working demo [here](https://codepen.io/Utsav91/pen/pojrYad?editors=0011)

You can read more on local storage here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Setting an element to localStorage: `localStorage.yourItem = yourValue;`
Accessing it's value later: `localStorage.yourItem;`

```
function checkDarkMode () {
    if (localStorage.darkMode) {
        document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
}

function toggleDarkMode () {
    localStorage.darkMode = !(localStorage.darkMode);
    checkDarkMode();
}
```

And call `checkDarkMode` after page load.